# How can I use PowerShell to connect to an URL and read from an XML table on the target site?

Tags: powershell, url, scripting

I am writing a script using PowerShell to connect to an URL in order to read from a table located in VMware's Build Numbers and Versions of VMware ESXi.  Any samples or turn-key code available would be appreciated.

Lipotech

Comment: Maybe? https://www.baylyparker.com/2017/12/powercli-esxi-host-versions/

Comment: Look at `Invoke-Webrequest`

Comment: Once I connect to the URL, using Invoke-Webrequest, can you give me an example of a construct that can be used to read from the XML table published on the site and write it to an excel file. I know how to handle the headers.